# How to plot specific parts of a matrix in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matrix that represents temperature distribution in a hollow square plate (hope the attached figure helps). The problem is with the hollow part in the plate which doesn't represent any solid material so I need to exclude this part from the plot.

[image]

The simulation returns an `np.array()` with the temperature results (except of course for the hollow part). and this is the part where I define dimensions of the grid:

```
import numpy as np

plate_height = 0.4 #meters
hollow_square_height = 0.2 #meters

#discretization data
delta_x = delta_y = 0.05 #meters
grid_points_n = (plate_height/delta_x) + 1

grid = np.zeros(shape=(grid_points_n, grid_points_n))
# the simulation assures that the hollow part will remain zero valued.
```

So, how do I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the original data, you can *mask* the values that you don't want to be used in calculations, plots, etc.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [
    [11, 11, 12, 13],
    [9, 0, 0, 12],
    [8, 0, 0, 11],
    [8, 9, 10, 11]
]

#Here's what you have:
data_array = np.array(data)

#Mask every position where there is a 0:
masked_data = np.ma.masked_equal(data_array, 0)

#Plot the matrix:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.matshow(masked_data, cmap=plt.cm.autumn_r) #_r => reverse the standard color map
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace zeros by nan, nan values are ignored in any plot. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import nan,matrix

M = matrix([
    [20,30,25,20,50],
    [22,nan,nan,nan,27],
    [30,nan,nan,nan,20],
    [33,nan,nan,nan,31],
    [21,28,29,23,36]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.matshow(M, cmap=plt.cm.jet) # Show matrix color
plt.show()
```

You can replace zeros by nan in a matrix as follow:

```
from numpy import nan

A[A==0.0]=nan  # A is your matrix
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you.